# Product of product of all subset of size k of a set?

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

example given set={$1,2,3$} size={$2$}

then ($1,2),(2,3),(1,3$) so product of each is $2,6,3$ and the product is $2*6*3=36$ again.

so i was looking for a method to do ?

Comment: Look at the example where we don't know the values... $\{a,b,c\}$ and we're looking at the size two subsets.  We have $\{a,b\},\{a,c\},\{b,c\}$, their respective products: $ab,ac,bc$ and the product of these $a^2b^2c^2$.  Notice a pattern?  Okay, now, lets take this a few steps further... With our set as $\{a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots,a_n\}$ and us taking $k$-element subsets... how many times do you suppose $a_1$ appears?  (*Further hint: how many subsets of size $k-1$ are there of $\{a_2,a_3,\dots,a_n\}$*)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume the set we're dealing with is finite. Let $S = \{s_1, s_2, \cdots, s_n \}$, and fix the size we're considering as $k$.

There are $\frac{n!}{k! (n-k)!}$ total subsets of size $k$. Now each element of $S$ will be a member of some (but not all) of these subsets. In particular, if we force $s_j$ to be in subset, there are $k-1$ remaining members to pick from the remaining $n-1$ members of $S$. Thus, there are exactly $\frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}$ subsets  of size $k$ containing $s_j$.

Since this holds for any $j$, and muliplication in commutative, we find the value you're l0oking for, $V$ is given by:

$$V = \prod_{j=1}^{n}s_j^r$$
where $r$ is given by:
$$r = \frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}$$

---

Applying this to your example above, we have $n =3$ and $k=2$, which yields $r = 2$. Then we have:
$$\begin{align}
V &= 1^2 *2^2 *3^2 \\ &= 1*4*9 \\ &=36
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the $k-$sets of $\{a_1,\cdots,a_n \}$ each element will occur $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ times in a given set, so the product of the products of the sets will be $\color{red}{\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n} a_i \right)^{\binom{n-1}{k-1}}}$.

Comment: That assumes that the set in question is of the form $\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$ which was not stated as a requirement.